# Can't install SDK In Android

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I am Just Installing SDK in Ubuntu But When I install SDk it Shows
installation did not complete successfully. See the IDE log for detail

Here is the screen shot:
[image: Screen Shot of error]

Here is my IDE log:

[image: IDE log]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a couple of questions:
1. Which directory/folder you used for installing SDK? where is it located? 
2. Have you given a read/write permission for directory/folder?

Most of the time we have an issue of folder read/write permission to store something in Ubuntu.

I have installed Android SDK in Ubuntu successfully. Let me know if you have the same error again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem: Installation did not complete successfully see the IDE log for details

I have already solved this problem in windows 10. I will share my experiment to solve your problem. 
If you have Android Studio 3.6.1 (or whatever), you should find this path "\Android\android-sdk" - usually you find it in C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk - and find the emulator folder and delete it. After that, go in the these folders "\tools\bin" and copy the whole path. Open the command line program and write CD and paste that path and press Enter. Usually, you will see like this: "C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\bin>". After that, write "sdkmanager emulator" like:
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\bin> sdkmanager emulator
you will see the downloading and installing of the emulator. And, your problem will be solved.